# Eclipse: Navigate to inheritor / base declaration

Tags: eclipse

In Visual Studio + Resharper, I could hit `Alt+Home` to go from a method to the corresponding base class or interface declaration, and `Alt+End` to go from a base declaration to the implementation in a derived class. I could navigate source code pretty quickly, even when everything used interfaces rather than concrete classes.

Is this doable in Eclipse? I tried the type hierarchy, but it's far too slow to be useful for me.

Comment: Are you talking about the functionality achieved by CTRL+ MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT ? (I don't use VS)

Answer (score 4):

When selecting a method that implements an interface or overrides another method, there is a triangle shown in the left border of the java editor. Clicking this triangle navigates you to the overridden method or interface declaration.

Navigating from one base class to one of the derived classes is done by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. But this only gives you the type hierarchy which is really slow, if there are many derived classes.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [nWire for Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java) (I'm assuming you are coding in Java, it also works for PHP). nWire works with you while you code and instantly shows all possible code associations, including interface implementations. It can do a lot more.